# How does Apple accomplish animated GIFs in SMS messages?

Tags: ios

I just learned that since iOS 5.0, you can send an animated GIF in an SMS message.

Does anyone know how Apple is implementing it, given that UIImage and UIImageView do not offer an out-of-the-box solution for handling an animated GIFs?

Answer (score 0):

Animating a UIImageView ?

```
self.imgview_animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_1.jpg"],
                                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_2.jpg"],
                                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_3.jpg"],
                                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_4.jpg"],
                                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_5.jpg"],
                                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_6.jpg"],
                                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_7.jpg"],
                                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_8.jpg"],
                                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_9.jpg"],
                                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation_10.jpg"],nil];

self.imgview_animation.animationDuration = 4; // seconds
self.imgview_animation.animationRepeatCount = 1; // 0 = loops forever
[self.imgview_animation startAnimating];
```

Comment: This is how you animate a UIImageView (note the *View*), but as you can't send a UIImageView via mms, this is not relevant.